# ionic 3 - HttpClient response shows inn clear text or how to disable httpclient cache

Tags: rest, web-services, ionic-framework, https

This is for my understanding I am asking this question.

My client is telling, they are able to see service response in cache folder if the device is rooted/jailbreak. I am using `HTTPS`.

```
   import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpEventType, HttpEvent  } from '@angular/common/http';

   APIBASEURL = "https://........"

   //MARK:- HTTP GET  method
   getServiceData(path: string) {
    var APIFULLURL = this.APIBASEURL + path;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers = headers.set("Content-Encoding", 'gzip')
    headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', this.APIHeaderKey);
    headers = headers.set('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
    headers = headers.set('Cache-control', 'no-store');
    headers = headers.set('Expires', '0');
    headers = headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');

    //*****************Service Log ********************//
     console.log("==URL ===" + APIFULLURL);
    //*****************Service Log ********************//

    const req = new HttpRequest('GET', APIFULLURL,{
      headers: headers,
      reportProgress: true,
      withCredentials : true
    });

    return this.http.request(req).timeout(50000)

  }

  //MARK:- HTTP POST method
  postService(path: string, isLogin: boolean, serviceBody: any) {
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers = headers.set("Content-Encoding", 'gzip')
    headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', this.APIHeaderKey)
    headers = headers.set('Cache-control', 'no-cache');
    headers = headers.set('Cache-control', 'no-store');
    headers = headers.set('Expires', '0');
    headers = headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');


    var APIFULLURL =  this.APIBASEURL + path;

    //*****************Service Log ********************//
    console.log("==URL ===" + APIFULLURL);
    //*****************Service Log ********************//
    try {

      return this.http.post(APIFULLURL, JSON.stringify(serviceBody), { headers: headers, withCredentials : true} ).timeout(50000);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert("Error" + error)
    }
  }
```

when I call api service, `httpclient` is saving the response in the cache. I do not manually save in the cache or local storage.

problem is first to install and access the app, later jailbreak/ rooted, go directly to cache folder and see the service response clear text.

How can I encrypt this cache value? according to my knowledge, before the process, `HttpClient` save in the cache.

Please guide me how to encrypt the service response in the cache.

This is the high severity issue in my app.

How can I disable '`HttpClient` to keep it in the cache?

Comment: PLease if anybody, know answer give and close it. simply don't close, after researching my side only I came to StackOverflow.  nearly 3 days I spent , no answer for me.

Comment: Not the voter.. but why not encrypt data on server side and decrypt at client

Comment: Have to do in the client side.

Comment: Actually if  they encrypt data on client side, it will impact existing system, so have to do in client side